# How do I absolute position an element X% inside a container?

Tags: css

In my project I have a structure like this:

```
<div className='slot-view'>
    <div className='slot-view-drop-target'>
        <div className='element' />
        <div className='element' />
        <div className='element' />
    </div>
</div>
```

The `slot-view` is essentially the `window`, 100% width and height.

The `slot-view-drop-target` has a height and width equal to 80% of the height and is centered in middle of the `slot-view`.

Then I have `element`s with `top` and `left` properties that could change because of drag and drops. For storage purposes, I'm storing those `top` and `left` values as percentage values on my server and then converting them into `px` when I render the `element` because of the different contexts in which `element`s can show up.

**So what I'm trying to achieve is:**

**Get the left (or top) px value of the `slot-view-drop-target` in px and then add x% from that top/left location to place the `element` where I want it.**

Giving an `element` a `top` and `left` of 0% is going to translate to it being in the top-left corner of the `slot-view` when I want it to be in the top-left corner of the slot-view-drop-target.

For the purposes of the drag and drop library in React, I'm using absolute positioning and top/left. If I use relative positioning, when I move an element it can cause the other ones to jump, so that's a consideration here.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting `.slot-view-drop-target` to `position:relative`?

Comment: The container to position relative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your relative positioning context needs to be also brought to the .slot-view-drop-target therefore when you absolutely position the .elements within it, they will

1. Be outside of the flow which means they shouldn't interact
2. Be positioned in % the correct distance from the top left corner of .slot-view-drop-target

However, if you really need the top/left coordinate location of the .slot-view-drop-target then it's just some simple math with JS.

(screen-size.x * .1) = your starting x coordinate
(screen-size.y * .1) = your starting y coordinate

.1 is 1 (100%) - .8 (.slot-view-drop-target width, 80%) / 2
2 is because it's centered within the screen